# Representing a LEFT JOIN in a REST endpoint

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, api-design

I'm trying to stay reasonably RESTful with my api design, and one of the endpoints I need to generate something equivalent to a left join and I haven't been too happy with any of the options I've come up with.

I have some Device resources and I need an endpoint that will output the devices along with their last AccessRecord. Sometimes they won't have an AccessRecord if its a recently provisioned device, but I still want it in the list. This feels very un-REST, representing a resource thats not there but needs are needs.

I've thought about the following approaches:

1) /devices/last_access_records
return an array of Device resources with an additional "last_access_record" field added.

2) /devices/last_access_records
return an array of Device, AccessRecord tuples, with the AccessRecord being null if it doesn't exist.

3) /devices/last_access_records
return an array of Device, AccessRecord tuples, and does not included devices that don't have any AccessRecords and require the api consumer to make a second call to /devices to get all the devices and do their own diff.

And several others.

3 seems most correct from an api design perspective, and 2 is nice and Erlang-y but tuples don't translate well to json.

Are there some other clear/clean ways to represent this kind of thing in a RESTful api or is it just a condition where things break down and you make a tradeoff choice?

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question and I believe it agrees with your option 2 (have the value if it is not null and drop it otherwise): https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml#Empty/Null_Property_Values

I think your 1st or 2nd option works good whether you explicitly have null as AccessRecord's value or omitting it if there is no value (latter being more space/time efficient.) I would think option 1 is more appropriate if AccessRecord is a property of a Device per your design; option 2 otherwise.